# Can you transfer data from a Cognito form to an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: cognito-forms

Once the customer enters their information on the Cognito form, is there any way for the data to be transferred to an Excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Yes, you can export your entry data to Excel from the Entries page. You have the option to export all of your entries, or to run a search and then export the entries that are returned in your search. You can learn more about this in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/77/entries/exporting-entries).